# Using GMail system labels correctly

Tags: email, imap, gmail-imap, mailcore2

We refactored some of our code, pulled the latest MailCore2 version and are now experiencing some issues with Gmail.

We wanted to make good use of the **all mail** folder, in order to optimize network usage and energy impact. That's why we basically check only all mail, trash and spam. Those checks include new message checks as well as merging local changes. But our issue manifested with saving drafts.

<s>We added a message in all mail and then the \Drafts label. This seems not to work. At some point Gmail even added an additional \Drafts label (path: \Drafts). So I guess Drafts can only be added to the drafts folder itself and then be synchronized via the all mail folder.</s>

Is there a general rule how to handle "system labels" ? I have the feeling that there are so many edge cases... e.g. the inbox label can be attached to a message, whereas drafts, spam and bin behave 'totally' different.

We've already drawn a table mapping all label types to each other and specified both types of "adding behavior" (dragging a label on a message vs. dragging a message on a label).

Thank you for your ideas!

**Edit (05.10.2014):**

When adding the drafts label to an existing message, it must be named '\draft'. This works, but is weird, since the imap server returns the folder flag '\drafts'

Comment: **Important**: I just figured out, that Gmails draft folder/label needs to be named '\Draft' instead '\Drafts'.

Comment: Gmails labelling is all non-standard, and not well documented.  I don't believe there is any 'correct' way to use it, and trial and error is pretty much how it works.   However, are you confusing Labels and Flags?

Comment: No, Gmail is. For example: they ignore the message flag '\draft’ but you can add the x-gm-label '\draft' (which should be named '\draft**s**', since this is the folder flag they use to identify the drafts folder.

Comment: x-gm-label '\draft' is not the same as Gmail's Drafts label. It's just a user-created label like 'foo' and 'bar'. It has no special meaning to Gmail. Gmail's Drafts label is represented by the [Gmail]/Drafts folder, and it is distinct from IMAP's \Draft flag. Sorry for the confusion, but equating [Gmail]/Drafts and IMAP \Draft causes problems. You are correct that moving messages in or out of [Gmail]/Drafts is not allowed. The only way to get a message into [Gmail]/Drafts is to APPEND it there (or create a draft in the web interface).

Comment: Hi Jamie. But why does it work, when using '\draft'? Were able to download all the drafts and add the \draft label to our lokal drafts which where appended to All Mail first. In gmail there are shown in the [GMail]/Drafts folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the list of folders using `-[MCOIMAPSession fetchAllFoldersOperation]`.
Then check `-[MCOIMAPFolder flags]` and look for a folder with the flag `MCOIMAPFolderFlagDrafts`.

Here's more information about folders and labels on Gmail: https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions

(See "Special-Use Extension of the LIST command").

Comment: Hi Viêt. This is not the point I was concerned about. Fetching folders with flags is pretty straight forward. But what if you want to use the folders/labels? In MailCore I call [session storeLabelsOperationWithFolder:@"[GMail]\All Mail" uids:someUIDs kind:MCOIMAPStoreFlagsRequestKindAdd labels:@"\draft"] to add GMails draft label to messages. Where '\drafts' would made more sense, since the actual folder flag you are talking about is named '\drafts'.